# UITableView in UINavigationController Custom Animation

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to find a way to make a `UINavigationController` push a table row into the next view during the animation. So that when the user clicks the table row item it follows the animation while all the other rows push off the screen. I have looked into `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` but haven't found any luck. I have seen similar things done with apps that when you click on something, an image follows you through the transition and that is essentially what I am looking for. I don't want to burden anyone to code it for me, but if you have any pointers on what I should look into or what paths I should take that would be great.

Comment: please post some screen or animated gif to explain your question. your question seems to be unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is exactly what you are looking for. Although I am not sure that it will work in ios6.

http://dativestudios.com/blog/2013/09/29/interactive-transitions/

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for this tutorial.